# Importance of protecting questions

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

A new member has responded to a "SARS-CoV-2 synthetic origin" questions [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11746/are-the-conclusions-in-the-proximal-origin-of-sars-cov-2-legit) and [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/is-it-possible-for-coronavirus-or-sars-to-be-synthetic) with a "human origin" opinion expressed in a verbose, aggressive and non-technical manner.

I have now protected the questions.

I think the original question(s) are on-message. Phylogenetics has a long history of readdressing conspiracy that otherwise has potentially negative outcomes, e.g. threatening polio erradication in Africa e.g. [here](https://www.historyofvaccines.org/content/articles/debunked-polio-vaccine-and-hiv-link) and [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/428820a).

A dissenting voice is fine, but the lesson is protecting questions, meaning preventing posts from new users or low reputation users, is in fact a good idea. Perhaps delete most opinionated posts therein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have destroyed that user's account. We should have absolutely no tolerance for such people.